# Can I count the occurences for postgres array field?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, count, unnest

I have a table postgres that uses the array type of data, it allows some magic making it possible to avoid having more tables, but the non-standard nature of this makes it more difficult to operate with for a beginner.
I would like to get some summary data out of it.

Sample content:

```
CREATE TABLE public.cts (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    day timestamp NULL,
    ct varchar[] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ctrlcts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO public.cts
(id, day, ct)
VALUES(29, '2015-01-24 00:00:00.000', '{ct286,ct281}');
INSERT INTO public.cts
(id, day, ct)
VALUES(30, '2015-01-25 00:00:00.000', '{ct286,ct281}');
INSERT INTO public.cts
(id, day, ct)
VALUES(31, '2015-01-26 00:00:00.000', '{ct286,ct277,ct281}');
```

I would like to get the totals per array member occurence totalized, with an output like this for example:

```
name | value 
ct286 | 3
ct281 | 3
ct277 | 1
```

Comment: `ct277` has a count of  `1`, not `2`.

Comment: @gmb that's why I need a sql way to do it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  [Postgres function array `unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM cts, unnest(ct) as u(name)
GROUP BY name
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xwgJ94BW4tAeTDZ3ed6w3K/1)**:

```
| name  | cnt |
| ----- | --- |
| ct277 | 1   |
| ct281 | 3   |
| ct286 | 3   |
```